# dlmwrite in a loop using cell type as the name

Tags: matlab, for-loop, save

I would like to save my filenames by calling my cell names as:

```
 bench(1:15).applicationNames
```

in which they are like this:

```
ans = 

   'mvt'


ans = 

   'symm'
```

, etc.

Having tested all kinds of conversions (cellstr, char, sprintf), i can't seems to find the solution for saving my array as bellow in loop:

```
dlmwrite('result_<bench(a),applicationName>.csv'),[zz' sort(bench(a).norm)],',')
```

where each bench.application has a name on it as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf` in place of your first string:

```
sprintf('result_%s.csv',bench(a).application{:})
```

Edit: fixed, as it was pointed out to me that `bench.application` was a cellstring.

Comment: I have already used it this way, dlmwrite doesn't support cell inputs : `dlmwrite(sprintf('%s.csv',bench(1).application),[zz' sort(bench(1).norm)],',')
Error using sprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.`

Comment: Try replacing `bench(1).application` with `bench(1).application{:}`. Or `char(bench(1).application)`.

Comment: Normally when you access a cell array, e.g. using `c(i)`, you get the contents of the cell still wrapped by a cell. When you use `c{i}` instead, you get only the contents of the cell, without the cell wrapper. So, in your case you're getting the string, instead of a cellstring. `{:}` tells MATLAB to convert every cell in a cell matrix to it's actual contents - because you've only got one cell, this is the same as saying `application{1}`.